# How to bind a string to hotkey?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, hotkeys

I want to quick paste some different strings using hotkeys. For example if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in any input form it works like if I pasted `loremipsum`. Or it  may be some abbreviation, for example I enter `li`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and get `loremipsum`.

I'm using Linux Mint with KDE desktop.

*In Windows I could do it using AutoHotkey*

Comment: Answered here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38554/bind-strings-to-hotkey and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/280604/assign-hotkeys-to-paste-predefined-text

Comment: Please [don't cross-post to multiple stack exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, can you help me with this http://meta.superuser.com/questions/12007/how-to-choose-a-community ?

Answer (score 1):

Install **xbindkeys** and **xvkbd**

```
echo '"xvkbd -text loremipsum"
alt + l' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Comment: Should I simple write this two lines in console after installing?

Comment: Okay, it added two lines to file `.xbindkeysrc` in my home folder but prints `oremipsum`